# How to pass PNG from Java class to Native class in Android with Opencv

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to pass a `PNG` format image file to native class to perform alpha-blending using OpenCV. For that I need all the 4 channels of the PNG. The image file that I want to pass is in my assets folder. I would like to know what is the best way to pass it to the native class? Thank you.

I'm using with `Android Studio 3.3.2` and `OpenCV4Android 4.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always serialize the image to bytes and pass it to JNI code. There, inside JNI, you can deserialize it.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-007/

You can also pass object and extract it's fields inside JNI. But this will require some tweaking on JNI side

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-020/

Anyway, at some point, you will have to access data from Java and turn it into C/C++ format (e.g. structures used by OpenCV).

If you have access to the file, you can also pass location of the file (String) and read the file inside C/C++ code

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/